# How do I install the Sgrequests module?

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abdulrafay/Downloads/massage.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sgrequests import SgRequests 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sgrequests'
```

I am getting this error when I run the following code. Can't seem to figure out how to install this module. Cant find this on google or anywhere else.

```py
import shutil
import requests
import os
from lxml import etree
import json
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing.pool as mpool
import pdb
import logging
import string
from sgrequests import SgRequests 
import PyPDF2
from pathlib import Path
import csv
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

alphabet_string = string.ascii_lowercase
goelocator = Nominatim(user_agent="message_book")


class Main:
    thread_count = 3
    #session = requests.Session()
    session = SgRequests(proxy_country="us", dont_retry_status_codes_exceptions = set([403, 407, 503]))
    headers = {
    }
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://37.48.118.90:13042',
        'https': 'https://37.48.118.90:13042'
    }
    holder_names = [
        "Abilene, TX"
        ,"Akron, OH"
        ,"Albuquerque, NM"
        ,"Allentown, PA"
        ,"Amarillo, TX"
        ,"Asheville, NC"
        ,"Athens, GA"
        ,"Atlanta, GA"
        ,"Atlantic City, NJ"
        ,"Auburn, AL"
        ,"Augusta, GA"
        ,"Austin, TX"
        ,"Bakersfield, CA"
        ,"Baltimore, MD"
        ,"Barnstable, MA"
        ,"Baton Rouge, LA"
        ,"Beaufort, SC"
        ,"Beaumont, TX"
        ,"Bellingham, WA"
        ,"Bend, WA"
        ,"Bentonville, AR"
        ,"Billings, MT"
        ,"Binghamton, NY"
        ,"Birmingham, AL"
        ,"Blacksburg, VA"
        ,"Bloomington, IN"
        ,"Bonita Springs, FL"
        ,"Boston, MA"
        ,"Boulder, CO"
        ,"Bowling Green, KY"
        ,"Brentwood, NY"
        ,"Brooklyn, NY"
        ,"Bryan, TX"
        ,"Buffalo, NY"
        ,"Burlington, NC"
        ,"Caldwell, ID"
        ,"Cedar Rapids, IA"
        ,"Chambersburg, PA"
        ,"Champaign, IL"
        ,"Charleston, WV"
        ,"Charlette, NC"
        ,"Charlottesville, VA"
        ,"Chattanooga, TN"
        ,"Chicago, IL"
        ,"Chico, CA"
        ,"Cincinnati, OH"
        ,"Clarksville, TN"
        ,"Cleveland, OH"
        ,"Colorado Springs, CO"
        ,"Columbia, MO"
        ,"Columbia, SC"
        ,"Columbus, GA"
        ,"Columbus, OH"
        ,"Concord, CA"
        ,"Corona, CA"
        ,"Corpus Christi, TX"
        ,"Dallas, TX"
        ,"Dayton, OH"
        ,"Daytona Beach, FL"
        "Decataur, AL"
        ,"Denver, CO"
        ,"Des Moines, IA"
        ,"Dover, DE"
        ,"Durham, NC"
        ,"Eau Claire, WI"
        ,"Edison, NJ"
        ,"El Paso, TX"
        ,"Englewood, NJ"
        ,"Erie, PA"
        ,"Eugene, OR"
        ,"Evansville, IN"
        ,"Fargo, ND"
        ,"Fayetteville, AR"
        ,"Fayetteville, NC"
        ,"Flint, MI"
        ,"Florence, SC"
        ,"Fort Collins, CO"
        ,"Fort Lauderdale, FL"
        ,"Fort Myers, FL"
        ,"Fort Smith, AR"
        ,"Fort Wayne, IN"
        ,"Fresno, CA"
        ,"Gainesville, FL"
        ,"Gainesville, GA"
        ,"Grand Junction, CO"
        ,"Grand Rapids, MI"
        ,"Greeley, CO"
        ,"Green Bay, WI"
        ,"Greenville, NC"
        ,"Greenville, SC"
        ,"Gulfport-Biloxi, MS"
        ,"Hagerstown, MD"
        ,"Harrisburg, PA"
        ,"Hartford, CT"
        ,"Hattiesburg, MS"
        ,"Hayden, WA"
        ,"Hickory, NC"
        ,"High Point, NC"
        ,"Houston, TX"
        ,"Huntington, WV"
        ,"Huntsville, AL"
        ,"Idaho Falls, ID"
        ,"Indianapolis, IN"
        ,"Jackson, MI"
        ,"Jackson, MS"
        ,"Jackson, TN"
        ,"Jacksonville, FL"
        ,"Jacksonville, NC"
        ,"Janesville, WI"
        ,"Joplin, MO"
        ,"Kalamazoo, MI"
        ,"Kansas City, MO"
        ,"Kansas City, MO"
        ,"Kennewick, WA"
        ,"Killeen, TX"
        ,"Kingsport, TN"
        ,"Kingston, NY"
        ,"Knoxville, TN"
        ,"Lafayette, IN"
        ,"Lafayette, LA"
        ,"Lake Charles, LA"
        ,"Lakeland, FL"
        ,"Lakewood, NJ"
        ,"Lancaster, PA"
        ,"Lansing, MI"
        ,"Largo, FL"
        ,"Las Cruces, NM"
        ,"Las Vegas, NV"
        ,"Levittown, NY"
        ,"Lexington, KY"
        ,"Lincoln, NE"
        ,"Lindon, UT"
        ,"Little Rock, AR"
        ,"Longview, TX"
        ,"Los Angeles, CA"
        ,"Louisville, KY"
        ,"Lubbock, TX"
        ,"Lynchburg, VA"
        ,"Macon, GA"
        ,"Madera, CA"
        ,"Madison, WI"
        ,"McAllen, TX"
        ,"Medford, OR"
        ,"Melbourne, FL"
        ,"Memphis, TN"
        ,"Merced, CA"
        ,"Miami, FL"
        ,"Midland, TX"
        ,"Milwaukee, WI"
        ,"Minneapolis, MN"
        ,"Mobile, AL"
        ,"Modesto, CA"
        ,"Monroe, LA"
        ,"Montgomery, AL"
        ,"Myrtle Beach, SC"
        ,"Nashville, TN"
        ,"New Haven, CT"
        ,"New Orleans, LA"
        ,"Norfolk, VA"
        ,"North Charleston, SC"
        ,"Norwalk, CT"
        ,"Norwich, CT"
        ,"Ocala, FL"
        ,"Oklahoma City, OK"
        ,"Olympia, WA"
        ,"Omaha, NE"
        ,"Orlando, FL"
        ,"Oshkosh, WI"
        ,"Oxnard, CA"
        ,"Panama City, FL"
        ,"Pensacola, FL"
        ,"Peoria, IL"
        ,"Philadelphia, PA"
        ,"Phoenix, AZ"
        ,"Pittsburgh, PA"
        ,"Port St Lucie, FL"
        ,"Portland, OR"
        ,"Prescott, AZ"
        ,"Pueblo, CO"
        ,"Punta Gorda, FL"
        ,"Queens, NY"
        ,"Raleigh, NC"
        ,"Raleigh, NC"
        ,"Reading, PA"
        ,"Redding, CA"
        ,"Reno, NV"
        ,"Richmond, VA"
        ,"Roanoke, VA"
        ,"Rochester, NY"
        ,"Rockford, IL"
        ,"Sacramento, CA"
        ,"Saginaw, MI"
        ,"Saint Louis, MO"
        ,"Saint Peters, MO"
        ,"Salem, OR"
        ,"Salisbury, MD"
        ,"Salt Lake City, UT"
        ,"San Antonio, TX"
        ,"San Diego, CA"
        ,"San Jose, CA"
        ,"San Luis Obispo, CA"
        ,"Sarasota, FL"
        ,"Savannah, GA"
        ,"Scarsdale, NY"
        ,"Schenectady, NY"
        ,"Seattle, WA"
        ,"Shreveport, LA"
        ,"Sioux Falls, SD"
        ,"South Bend, IN"
        ,"South Ogden, UT"
        ,"Southfield (Detroit), MI"
        ,"Spring Valley, NY"
        ,"Springfield, IL"
        ,"Springfield, MA"
        ,"Springfield, MO"
        ,"St. George, UT"
        ,"Stamford, CT"
        ,"State College, PA"
        ,"Stockton, CA"
        ,"Stroudsburg, PA"
        ,"Syracuse, NY"
        ,"Tallahassee, FL"
        ,"Tampa, FL"
        ,"The Bronx, NY"
        ,"Toledo, OH"
        ,"Topeka, KS"
        ,"Trentwood, WA"
        ,"Tucson, AZ"
        ,"Tulsa, OK"
        ,"Tuscaloosa, AL"
        ,"Tyler, TX"
        ,"Utica, NY"
        ,"Vero Beach, FL"
        ,"Visalia, CA"
        ,"Waco, TX"
        ,"Washington, DC"
        ,"Waterloo, IA"
        ,"Wayne, NJ"
        ,"Wells Branch, TX"
        ,"West Palm Beach, FL"
        ,"Wichita, KS"
        ,"Williamsburg, VA"
        ,"Willkes-Barre, PA"
        ,"Wilmington, NC"
        ,"Yakima, WA"
        ,"York, PA"
        ,"Youngstown, OH"
        ,"Yuba City, CA"
        ,"Yuma, AZ"
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_requests()
        
    def start_requests(self):
        for holder_name in self.holder_names:
            # for alpha in alphabet_string[5:]:
            print(holder_name)
            business_list_url = f'https://www.massagebook.com/nxt/pu-api/v1/businesses?limit=100&offset=0&filters=latitude%3D%3D{location.latitude},longitude%3D%3D{location.longitude}'
            response = self.session.get(business_list_url, headers={
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
            })
            dummy_data = json.loads(response.text)

            for item in dummy_data['data']:
                attribute = item['attributes']
                business_name = attribute['business_name']
                try:
                    phone = attribute['phone']['number']
                except:
                    phone = ''

                address_1 = attribute['address_1']
                address_2 = attribute['address_2']
                city = attribute['city']
                state = attribute['state']
                zip = attribute['zip']
                street = f'{address_1} {address_2}, {city}, {state}, {zip}'
                website = attribute['website_url']
                id = item['id']
                staff_url = f'https://www.massagebook.com/nxt/pu-api/v1/businesses/{id}/staff-members?limit=1&offset=0&includes=state_licenses,other_licenses,reviews,reviews.service_category&filters=can_provide_services%3D%3Dtrue'
                time.sleep(1.5)
                response = self.session.get(staff_url, headers={
                    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
                })
                first_name = ''
                last_name = ''
                staff_name = ''
                try:
                    staff_data = json.loads(response.text)
                    staff = staff_data['data'][0]
                    if staff:
                        first_name = staff['attributes']['first_name']
                        last_name = staff['attributes']['last_name']
                        staff_name = f'{first_name} {last_name}'
                except:
                    # pdb.set_trace()
                    print(staff_data)
                data = [business_name, phone, street, website, staff_name]
                print(data)
                with open('data.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    # write the data
                    writer.writerow(data)
                    f.close()
                print(item['id'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: What is `sgrequests`? Where did you hear about it? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I was given this script by someone else to understand it. While executing it gave me the above mentioned error. I tried googling this sgrequest module but I cant find any documentation on it whatsoever so i thought I should ask about it on stack overflow.

Comment: Is there a possibility it was a user written module and not on PyPi? I've never heard of that library. It certainly isn't well known.

Comment: Maybe, Because I cant seem to find it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).